# HtmlAgility remove attribute from style parameter of Div node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am stuck trying to remove a style definition from the style attribute of a DIV element.
HTML code:

```
<div class="el1" style="width:800px; max-width:100%" />
...

<div class="el2" style="width:800px; max-width:100%" />
```

There may be more than 1 of these elements that I need to apply the manipulation to.

Here is what I have thus far using HtmlAgilityPack.

```
foreach (HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style]"))
{
  if (div != null)
  {
    div.Attributes["style"].Value["max-width"].Remove(); //Remove() does not appear to be a function
  }
 }
```

My thought process was to select any  with a style attribute. Look for a max-width definition and remove it.

Any guidance on how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can't do it like that. You can only get the `style` value. From there on you can remove the `max-width` by using a reg-ex or some other diabolical contraption and finally set it back on the attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THanks Marcel for pointing me to the right direction:

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
HtmlNodeCollection divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style]");
            if (divs != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode div in divs)
                {
                    string style = div.Attributes["style"].Value;
                    string pattern = @"max-width(.*?)(;)";
                    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    string newStyle = regex.Replace(style, String.Empty);
                    div.Attributes["style"].Value = newStyle;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it works great! Why don't you mark your own answer as the accepted one?

Comment: I used this approach to remove all height styles from td tags but not from tr tags. Worked like a charme!